# Automorphisms of order 3 in $C_2$ X $C_2$ X $C_2$

Tags: finite-groups, automorphism-group

I am trying to find out the number of automorphisms there are in  $C_2$ $\times$ $C_2$ $\times$ $C_2$ $\cong <x,y,z|x^2=y^2=z^2=1>$. I only can come up with the one which moves $x \rightarrow y \rightarrow z \rightarrow x$ and the inverse. However, the problem is that I watched a proyect which says that there are 54 elements of order 3 in the Aut$(C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2)$. I do not know whether I am wrong or the proyect.

Comment: First, the presentation is not correct, as it is missing the commutation relations. Second, the automorphism group here is $GL_3(2) = PSL_3(2)$ which is a simple group of order $168$. So it cannot have just $2$ elements of order $3$, since then it would not be simple.

Comment: To see that there are more than those 2, you can explicitly count more possibilities, e.g. (using additive notation) $x \mapsto x+y$ and permutations of this. Other options: $x \mapsto 0$, $y \mapsto x$, $z\mapsto x +y$...

Comment: Regarding Tobias' comment, yes, I had forgoten to write the commutation relations and i do not see why the automorphism group is $GL_3(2)$. Movin on to the inquisitor's comment, you are right, I did not realised of that type of possibilities, thanks.